# Connection spark streaming to kafka within eclipse: error-Couldn't find leader offsets

Tags: eclipse, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am using spark streaming v2.0.0 and kafka v08.2.1

I am trying to connect spark streaming to a remote kafka server by using eclipse.
To create the topic I used the following guide: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart
I used the example provided in spark streaming to write the following code:

```
package sparkstreamingtest;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils;
import scala.Tuple2;
public class test1 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {   
    String brokers = "10.66.125.130:9092";//args[0];//on récupère hosts:port
    String topics = "test2";//args[1];//on récupère les topics de kafka: topic1,topic2,..

    // Create context with a 2 seconds batch interval
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaDirectKafkaWordCount").setMaster("local[*]");
    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(2));

    HashSet<String> topicsSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(topics.split(",")));//on sépare les topics pour les mettre dans un même set
    System.out.println(topicsSet);
    HashMap<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", brokers);//même chose pour les hosts (brokers)
    System.out.println(kafkaParams);
    // Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
    JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
        jssc,
        String.class,
        String.class,
        StringDecoder.class,
        StringDecoder.class,
        kafkaParams,
        topicsSet
    );
    // Get the lines, split them into words, count the words and print
    JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
      @Override
      public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
        return tuple2._2();
      }
    });
    // Start the computation
    jssc.start();
    jssc.awaitTermination();
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error that I don't understand:

```
16/08/19 10:53:58 INFO SimpleConsumer: Reconnect due to socket error: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Couldn't find leader offsets for Set([test2,0])
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$checkErrors$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$checkErrors$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:373)
    at scala.util.Either.fold(Either.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$.checkErrors(KafkaCluster.scala:372)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.getFromOffsets(KafkaUtils.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:484)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:607)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala)
    at sparkstreamingtest.test1.main(test1.java:64)
16/08/19 10:53:59 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

I can't achieve to solve even if I followed the former stackoverflow subjects:

[Spark Streaming + Kafka: SparkException: Couldn't find leader offsets for Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288449/spark-streaming-kafka-sparkexception-couldnt-find-leader-offsets-for-set)

[Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Couldn't find leaders for Set()-Spark Steaming-kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792611/exception-in-thread-main-org-apache-spark-sparkexception-org-apache-spark-spa)

[Cannot connect from Spark Streaming to Kafka: org.apache.spark.SparkException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788424/cannot-connect-from-spark-streaming-to-kafka-org-apache-spark-sparkexception-j)

[How to manually commit offset in Spark Kafka direct streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635381/how-to-manually-commit-offset-in-spark-kafka-direct-streaming)

can anyone help me in this issue ?

Thank you for your attention and your help.

Joe

Comment: Have you found the solution? I'm stuck exactly at the same problem!

Comment: I think checkpoint is the missing part    [ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/KafkaWordCount.scala)